Movie about transplants?
Help me identify this movie: world in which transplanted organs give memories of the donator to the transplanted one. 
I'm not really sure and I'm sorry if I can't be able to give more informations about it, but I think it could also be an eye transplant that makes the protagonist remember memories and flashbacks from the donator. 
American or British production, light cinematography, also I saw it more than ten years ago.
Note: It certainly wasn't an horror. I remember a scene in a ospital and the protagonist was 99% a woman (with short hair or something).

Was it the eye or the remake?

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Any other plot details or descriptions you can give? Anything at all?

There is a movie I watched (don't remember the name) where the person received an eye transplant where the eye came from a murderer or some type of serial felon. The receiver started seeing things from the murderer's point of view and later started committing the murders themselves because of this ... or something to that effect. Don't know if that is the right movie for the OP, but if it is, someone else maybe has a better memory of it than I do.

@Paulster2 Maybe you're talking about Eyes of Laura Mars? But unfortunately it's not the one I was talking about

No, quite different than that ... this one had transplants going on, where Eyes seems to be about clairvoyance.

Cate, please update your details, I've got an indian movie from 2005 that fits your description but I don't even know the language of the movie you're searching for.

@mGolos Could your movie be a remake of mine?

It seems to be yet another remake of the original Chinese movie 'The Eye'. I don't think it's what you're looking for but it's Naina (2005),

I need more information to post an answer, but is it Blink (1994)? She doesn't seem to have short hair, but it's not a horror movie and involves an eye transplantation, psychic experiences and a serial killer. Let me know if I'm right and I'll post an answer you can accept.

Yes! Thank you @mGoLos, it is Blink. I had very few memories, since I saw it so many years ago. Thank you again.

You're looking for Blink (1994)


Emma is a blind cellist who finally gets the opportunity to get to
  see. Meanwhile, a string of bizarre rapes and murders has taken place.
  All of the victims have had transplants within the last month. A
  coincidence, or is Emma next?

While there wasn't much information to work with, the field was narrowed a lot with the details you did offer and the synopsis seemed to fit quite nicely. The exclusion of the horror genre was actually very helpful in my research effort.
